# Set top and bottom row border in excel 2010

Tags: c#

this is my code to set the top and bottom border for row ("A4 - E4").

```
            //Frame insert
            Excel.Range ExFrame;
            ExFrame = ExcelWorkbook.get_Range("A4", "E4");
            ExFrame.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop];
            ExFrame.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeBottom];
```

Why does this not run?

Can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: The formatting of your code looks as if 'Frame' is a reserved word in this context.

When you say this does not run, what exactly happens? Does the code compile?

Comment: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement (CS0201) -                      This is the error i get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing each border type (EdgeTop, EdgeBottom) but not doing anything with them. You need to change these properties in some way, e.g.:

```
ExFrame.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
```